# SQL запрос (please help)

Tags: mysql, sql

Прошу помочь.
Есть две таблицы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Первая табл: связь физических книг и эл.книг (IDB и IDEB - уникальные, т.е одной эл.книге соотв. - только одна физ.книга и наоборот);
Вторая табл.(таблица комментариев):
в поле ID хранятся все id как эл., так и физических.
Собственно вопрос:
как вытащить количество MARK (count)  по заданному(input) массиву IDB(1,2,3,7), чтобы в результирующей таблице было следующее:

### OOPCOMMENTS.ID, count(MARK)

где count(MARK) это сумма МАRK IDEB + IDB (при условии если эта связь есть, при ее отсутствии брать только со 2 таблицы) 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Делайте внятный заголовок, а не `SQL запрос (please help)`. Это уже второй подобный вопрос. Всё таки это ресурс - база знаний, где люди должны находить вопросы-ответы с подобными проблемами, а не являться вашим личным SQL-helper

Comment: Предложите какой?

Comment: http://sql-ex.ru например

Comment: Спасибо. Пример sql запроса сбросишь? Или так и будешь обсир..ть

Comment: Спасибо за предложение, учту. Попробуй написать, конечно если сможешь. И пишу сюда т.к сам не могу допетрить!

Comment: Я сразу сказал, что не могу написать запрос, потому что не могу понять, какой результат должен быть после его выполнения. вам сложно привести ожидаемый результат выполнения на основе показанных данных. просто в виде таблички, колонок с ожидаемыми значениями ?

Comment: Up. Обновил. Думаю - должно быть понятно.

Comment: Я же правильно понимаю, что может быть наоборот, если бы в левой таблице были бы в последней строке значения 6,3 вместо 3,6 ведь запись все равно должна бы найтись ?

Comment: Хотя видимо не правильно понимаю ... Там же на входе IDB, значит в левой таблице именно по этой колонке искать ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t.ID ID, count(t.ID) MARK FROM (
    SELECT o.ID
    FROM OOPCOMMENTS o
    WHERE o.ID IN ( 1, 3, 7 )                                   
    UNION ALL
    SELECT EBOOKS4B.IDB
    FROM OOPCOMMENTS, EBOOKS4B
    WHERE EBOOKS4B.IDB IN ( 1, 3, 7  )
    AND OOPCOMMENTS.ID = EBOOKS4B.IDEB) as t
 group by t.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Если в ebooks искать дополнения только по колонке IDB:

```
select id, sum(mark)
  from oopcomments
 where id in(1,3,7)
    OR id in( select ideb from ebooks4b where idb in(1,3,7) )
 group by id
```